# Pass multiple parameters using sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sp-executesql

I am using SQL Server 2016 to write a stored procedure with dynamic SQL and `sp_executesql` with multiple parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testsp] @ProductName nvarchar(250), @ProductDescription nvarchar(250)
AS

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @query = 'EXEC (''INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products] ([ProductName], [ProductDescription]) VALUES (?,?)'', @ProductName, @ProductDescription) AT [linkedserver]' 
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ProductName nvarchar(250), @ProductDescription nvarchar(250)', @ProductName, @ProductName;
```

> Error: Must pass parameter number 2 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'. After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'

I need to make a jdbc call of the stored procedure.

```
call [dbo].[testsp](?,?)
```

Comment: Also I need to get the name of the linked server dynamically. If the environment is DEV then the name of linked server would be [LinkedServer_DEV], TEST would be [LinkedServer_TEST].

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this question correctly, you need to define the stored procedure in the following way to use `EXECUTE .. AT` (using the `?` syntax). Note, that `[linkedserver]` must refer to an existing linked server definition in the local server.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testsp] 
    @ProductName nvarchar(250), 
    @ProductDescription nvarchar(250)
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'linkedserver', 'SQL Server'  

    DECLARE @err int

    EXECUTE (
        N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products] ([ProductName], [ProductDescription]) VALUES (?, ?)', 
        @ProductName, @ProductDescription
    ) AT [linkedserver]  

    SELECT @err = @@ERROR
    RETURN @err
END
```

If you want to use `sp_executesql`, you need to create the stored procedure using the following statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testsp] 
    @ProductName nvarchar(250), 
    @ProductDescription nvarchar(250)
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'linkedserver', 'SQL Server'  

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @err int

    SET @sql = 
        'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products] ([ProductName], [ProductDescription]) '+
        'VALUES (@ProductName, @ProductName)' 
    EXEC @err = [linkedserver]...sp_executesql 
       @sql, 
       N'@ProductName nvarchar(250), @ProductDescription nvarchar(250)',
       @ProductName, @ProductName;

    RETURN @err
END
```

As an additional explanation, you do not need to mix [EXECUTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in this situation. Select one of these two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
use tempdb  
go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [ProductName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [ProductDescription] [varchar](300) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]



DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @query = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products] ([ProductName], [ProductDescription]) VALUES (@ProductName,@ProductDescription)' 
  EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@ProductName varchar(250), @ProductDescription varchar(250)', @ProductName='ProductNameVal', @ProductDescription='ProductDescriptionVal';

  select * from Products

+----------------+-----------------------+
|  ProductName   |  ProductDescription   |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| ProductNameVal | ProductDescriptionVal |
+----------------+-----------------------+
```

If  you want to execute it in the remote server you can try it as below;
[Executing remote stored procedure within sp_executesql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904210/executing-remote-stored-procedure-within-sp-executesql)

```
EXEC remoteserver.database.dbo.sp_executesql 'dynamic SQL'
```